# setting different region for differnt services of AWS in zend framework 2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zend-framework2

I am using **AWS** with php sdk for zf2 and using its two services, first one is ses(mail service) and other one is S3 service.

I have these services already in different regions, so by using the config file (**aws.local.php**), I can only specify one at a time as per default.

So I want to use two different regions, one for s3 and one for ses.

- How can I do that?

Below is sample code i am using for s3.

```
 $aws= $this->getServiceLocator()->get('aws');
        $client = $aws->get('s3');
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [creating a client section of the AWS SDK for PHP docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html#creating-a-client). You can create a client using the client's corresponding create method from the AWS\Sdk class. Note that the [createS3 factory method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.Sdk.html#m_createS3) (and other service factory methods) take an array of arguments. The common arguments that all service clients accept are documented in [the Aws\AwsClient::__construct() method documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.AwsClient.html#___construct). We can see `region` is one of the options so you can specify the region for individual services like so:

```
$myConfig = [
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
];
// Create an Amazon S3 client using the shared configuration data.
$client = $sdk->createS3($myConfig);
```

**Edit** based the comment asking for info on v2 of the PHP SDK:
The best option for you is to upgrade to the latest version of the SDK. It's a major release with many improvements so I strongly encourage you to update.
However, with v2 you can do something similar using the corresponding web service client's factory() method. For example, for S3 you could use something like the following:

```
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
));
```

The [AWS PHP SDK Quick Start topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html) has more details.

Comment: i m getting follwing error
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Aws\Common\Aws::createS3() in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\IndexController.php on line 507
and my code is 
 $aws    = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('aws'); $myConfig = [
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
];
            $client = $aws->createS3($myConfig);

Comment: Double check that you have the latest version of the aws-php sdk. If you continue to get the same error, try using the `createClient` method instead of createS3: `$aws->createClient('s3', $myConfig)` . If you continue to have problems also add the code that shows how inject the AWS class/service into Zend service manager. In fact, it will be best to try your code directly with the S3 client instead of using the service manager (i.e. don't use getServiceLocator) just to see if the service manager is part of the problem.

Comment: actaully i am using version 2 of aws ,not the latest one v3,could you please suggest me how to do this in version 2

Comment: @user3522412 did we get you going here?